# Form gets submitted twice on button click

Tags: javascript

I have called below javascript function on

```
function formOnSubmit() {
  if (document.forms[0].ref_no.value == "") {
    if (document.forms[0].acc_code.value == "") {
      if (document.forms[0].vendor_code.value == "") {
        if (document.forms[0].acc_service_tax.value == "") {
          if (document.forms[0].acc_doc_name.value == "") {
            alert('Please enter atleast one attribute value');
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    return true;
    document.forms[0].submit();
  }
}
```

where,
ref_no,acc_code,vendor_code,acc_service_tax,acc_doc_name are textboxes

The problem is form gets submitted twice when I enter something in ref_no texbox and form submitss once for the rest of textboxes.

I want to know why form gets submitted twice when I enter ref_no value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you call the function on a input which button type is submit, you need to remove the following line:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

Also this function generally should bind to the button as a onclick which actually just be:

```
onclick="return formOnSubmit()"
```

Answer (score 15):

Adding below given line solved my problem.

```
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Comment: Perfect! Can you explain why?

Comment: The stopImmediatePropagation() method of the Event interface prevents other listeners of the same event from being called @tushar747

Comment: Worked pefectly for me!

Answer (score 11):

Finally got it straight for myself, and hopefully for others. If you are using a "button" and want to use `document.forms[0],submit()`, then specify the button `type="button"`.  Otherwise, the default button type will be used, which is `submit`, and in my case with **IE** your form will be submitted twice.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem but in my case was a little diferent:
My code js:

```
$btnSave.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $formPreRequisites.trigger('submit');
});
```

And my form submit:

```
$myForm.on('submit', function (e) {
    //mythings
});
```

Then I was having this problem with two calls of my button submit in 'on click' event. Then I put this in my method and it works. This prevents the event propagate in my html DOM elements.

```
$btnSave.on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $myForm.trigger('submit');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

change your input type "**submit**" to "**button**"

example

```
<input  type="button" value="submit" onClick=formOnSubmit(); />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use any one that is in else condition.

Use either:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

else

```
return true;
```

And if you are using the `return true` in else condition then the function call in form tag on `onSubmit` event.

```
<form action="//your action" method="//your method" onsubmit="return formOnSubmit()">
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

**Click handler function inside another click handler function attaches the same click handler multiple times based on the sum of clicks**

This is not the solution for your example but a solution for the same problem. I added a click handler that prevents the form submit and opens a modal with a button. After you click the button in the modal the form should get submitted on the defined circumstances.

So far so good. But my code for the button click inside the modal was inside the scope of the outer click handler. So after you opened up the modal twice the form was submitted twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the function submit() and you have a submit button in your form , it surely will submit twice , turn the submit button to button or delete the line you called the submit() function